# ng add @angular/fire "The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics"

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

I've just updated to Angular CLI 12.0.0, using Node 14.17.0, and npm 7.13.0

When I try to add Angular Fire to my project

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

I get the message:

> The package @angular/fire@0.0.0 will be installed and executed.
> Would you like to proceed? Yes
> ✔ Package successfully installed.
> The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.

Using `npm uninstall @angular/fire` doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated!

**NOTE:** as @deelde mentioned below, this is a new, [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2832), so for the time being, I've reverted to Angular CLI v11.2.13, and it's working.

Uninstall:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

To make sure the uninstall worked, this should give an error:

```
ng --version
```

Reinstall Angular CLI v11

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.13
```

Comment: in Angular CLI 12.0.2, the message has changed to mention a race condition. When I rerun the command as-is, it's been working for me the 2nd time

Answer (score 5):

there is an open issue in github with this behaviour. It seems to be a problem with a module called "blueprint" in angular/fire version 6.1.4.

[Github Issue: Unable to ng add @angular/fire on first try on Angular 12 in brand new app](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2832)

The author mentioned that if he executed the command a second time, everything worked.

Another option could be to install the package via npm install and then execute ng add:

```
npm install @angular/fire@6.1.4
ng add @angular/fire@6.1.4 --verbose
```

Comment: thanks for the info! unfortunately the lines didn't work for me, even with "--legacy-peer-deps" added to the npm install

Answer (score 4):

Angular Fire for now do not support angular12, so you should use the latest version of angular fire:

```
ng add @angular/fire@latest
```

Comment: with that, I get the message "npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running:

terminal > `curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`

this comes from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-mac-linux

then running

```
ng generate environments
npm install @angular/fire
ng add @angular/fire
```